# Is it possible to retrieve the underlying user from a proxyConnection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, proxy

```
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, schema);
oracleConnection.openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME,prop);
```

Using the above snippet, we can create a proxy connection from a oracle jdbc connection. And PHIL is the proxy user for the proxy connection. How do we obtain the original user?

Is there any API in OracleConnection which would provide the information?

`oracleConnection.getUserName()` would just return the user used for the connection.

Is it possible to remove proxy connection out of proxy connection and just return back the old jdbc connection?

Comment: At least you should be able to to see it in auditing tables. If auditing is turned on.

Comment: @ibre5041: ok. I wanted to programatically retrieve it, based on a use-case

Answer (score 0):

Calling `oracleConnection.close(OracleConnection.PROXY_SESSION)` will close the proxy-client's session (JEFF in your example) and the connection will be switched to the original 'parent' session. From there if you call `getUserName()` again you should get the 'parent' session user name.